# Redisson best practice config with example

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I config **Redisson** client like below, as part of **Singelton** , what is the best practice to improve performance by redissson config ?
and what is best way to invalidate object at Redisson map ?

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress(redisProperties.getProperty(RedisProperties.REDIS_ENDPOINT)+":"+Integer.valueOf(redisProperties.getProperty(RedisProperties.REDIS_PORT)));

config.useSingleServer().setRetryAttempts(3);
config.useSingleServer().setTimeout(10000);
config.useSingleServer().setConnectionPoolSize(500);
config.useSingleServer().setRetryInterval(2000);
redisson = (Redisson) Redisson.create(config);
```

example of use :

```
RMapCache<String, Object> map = RedissonAcess.getInstance().getRedissonClient().getMapCache(currentDBUrl+mapName.getValue());

map.put(key, value,3,TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: Use `fastPut` instead of `put` when previous values is not required